# Creating a simple addition form application programmatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to create a simple addition program in vb.net form application. Also i want to create all controls programmatically. I have three text boxes and one button. When the button is clicked , it take value from two text boxes and assign it to the third text box value. 
I am unable to get text boxes string from button click handle.

My coding is as follows:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Pushbutton
        Dim PushButton As New Button()
        PushButton.Text = "Add"
        PushButton.Location = New Point(10, 100)
        Me.Controls.Add(PushButton)
        AddHandler PushButton.Click, AddressOf myButtonHandler_Click
        '
        'TextBox1
        Dim TextBox1 As New TextBox
        TextBox1.Location = New Point(10, 3)
        Me.Controls.Add(TextBox1)

        'TextBox2
        Dim TextBox2 As New TextBox
        TextBox2.Location = New Point(200, 3)
        Me.Controls.Add(TextBox2)


        Dim TextBox3 As New TextBox
        TextBox3.Location = New Point(200, 100)
        Me.Controls.Add(TextBox3)

    End Sub

    Private Sub myButtonHandler_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Public Function ADD(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
        ADD = x + y
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Declare your Controls as instance Fields and use [double.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse) to validate the input. Possibly, give those controls meaningful names. Or use a class object that generates all the needed parts (controls included), which contains all the logic required (including the `Add()` method), so you have a reusable object and you don't need to litter your Form.

Comment: Use [`NumericUpDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown) instead of `TextBox`, then no parsing is required...

Comment: My question is not about that, am unable to get text boxes values from "Private Sub myButtonHandler_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)", so how to get these values.

Comment: My comment is just an additional suggestion to Jimi's comment, which is a short answer to your question. The problem is that you can't access the textbox-objects because they're declared inside `Form_Load`. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels)

Comment: If you don't want to assign the controls to dedicated fields then you can get them back from the `Controls` collection by name. Of course, you have to give them a `Name` value when you create them to do that. Otherwise, you could get them back by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the declaration of the controls to Form level allows them to be seen in all the methods of the form.

```
Public Class Form3
    Private TextBox1 As New TextBox
    Private TextBox2 As New TextBox
    Private TextBox3 As New TextBox
    Private PushButton As New Button

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Pushbutton
        PushButton.Text = "Add"
        PushButton.Location = New Point(10, 100)
        Me.Controls.Add(PushButton)
        AddHandler PushButton.Click, AddressOf myButtonHandler_Click

        'TextBox1
        TextBox1.Location = New Point(10, 3)
        Controls.Add(TextBox1)

        'TextBox2
        TextBox2.Location = New Point(200, 3)
        Controls.Add(TextBox2)

        'TextBox3
        TextBox3.Location = New Point(200, 100)
        Controls.Add(TextBox3)
    End Sub

    Private Sub myButtonHandler_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim firstNumber = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim secondNumber = CDbl(TextBox2.Text)
        TextBox3.Text = ADD(firstNumber, secondNumber).ToString
    End Sub

    Public Function ADD(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
        ADD = x + y
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can technically do it the way you were, but only if you use an **anonymous event handler** for the button click event as shown below:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TextBox1
        Dim TextBox1 As New TextBox
        TextBox1.Location = New Point(10, 3)
        Me.Controls.Add(TextBox1)

        'TextBox2
        Dim TextBox2 As New TextBox
        TextBox2.Location = New Point(200, 3)
        Me.Controls.Add(TextBox2)

        Dim TextBox3 As New TextBox
        TextBox3.Location = New Point(200, 100)
        Me.Controls.Add(TextBox3)

        'Pushbutton
        Dim PushButton As New Button()
        PushButton.Text = "Add"
        PushButton.Location = New Point(10, 100)
        Me.Controls.Add(PushButton)
        AddHandler PushButton.Click, Sub()
                                         Dim dblA, dblB As Double
                                         If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, dblA) AndAlso Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, dblB) Then
                                             TextBox3.Text = ADD(dblA, dblB)
                                         Else
                                             MessageBox.Show("One or more Invalid Inputs")
                                         End If
                                     End Sub
    End Sub

    Public Function ADD(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
        ADD = x + y
    End Function

End Class
```

Though I do recommend moving those control declarations out to Form level as Mary suggested.